# How to manage zappa settings to dev environment using django

Tags: python, django, zappa, python-zappa

What is the best practices to manage dev enviroment using zappa? Currently I have my `zappa_settings.json` in my project and inside it I have api urls, keys etc. when I deploy It to AWS these keys will be used correctly like:

`API_KEY = os.getenv('API_KEY')`

the code above will get the `API_KEY` from my `zappa_seetings.json`

```json
{
    "prod": {
        "API_KEY": "example 2938u2983j0fy28394yf2j98340j20934"
    }
}
```

But what if I want to run the code locally? I'll need to create a `.env` file with the same enviroment keys and every time I change the `zappa_settings.json` file I'll need to change the .env file too? If there is a different way to do it, I would like to know.